# Core Data way to perform SQL join request

Tags: ios, sql, objective-c, core-data

I'm trying to implement simple inventory-type database. I have a list of devices on player's spaceship, each device can be in activated/deactivated state. 
Problem is that I want to keep data about device specifications in separate entity called DeviceData, so Core Data scheme will look like this:
[a busy cat http://rghost.ru/57018961/image.png](http://rghost.ru/57018961/image.png)

And i'm fetching data with this request:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"SpaceshipDevice"] init];
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"deviceData.deviceName" ascending:NO]];
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20;

NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                                   initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                   managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                   sectionNameKeyPath:@"deviceData.deviceType"
                                   cacheName:nil];
frc.delegate = self;
self.fetchedResultsController = frc;
```

What I'm concerned about is an "instances" relationship in DeviceData the only purpose of which is to be an inverse of "deviceData" relationship of SpaceshipDevice entity. This makes me feel like something is wrong. Is there any better way to do it?

In SQL this request will look like this:

[a busy cat http://rghost.ru/57019185/image.png](http://rghost.ru/57019185/image.png)

Comment: From what I understand what you want it looks good.  the SpaceshipDevice table is how you would handle the many to many relationship between DeviceData and Spaceship.

Comment: @bowlturner yeah, but it's one to many, not many to many. If it is many to many, how could I specify sort descriptors like @"deviceData.deviceName"? As far as i understand it will be an NSSet property.